# Serial port data receiving issue

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'd like to read data from serial port but do not know how to do that.

I'm using Arduino, so here is my code for it:

```
    int switchPin = 7;
int ledPin = 13;
boolean lastButton = LOW;
boolean currentButton = LOW;
boolean flashLight = LOW;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

boolean debounce(boolean last)
{
  boolean current = digitalRead(switchPin);
  if (last != current)
  {
    delay(5);
    current = digitalRead(switchPin);
  }
  return current;
}

void loop()
{
  currentButton = debounce(lastButton);
  if (lastButton == LOW && currentButton == HIGH)
  {
    Serial.println("UP");

    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
  if (lastButton == HIGH && currentButton == LOW)
  {
    Serial.println("DOWN");

    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }

  lastButton = currentButton;
}
```

As you can see, everything is simple: after pressing the button device sends "DOWN" or "UP" to serial port.
I'd like to receive it from my WPF application.
Here comes it's code:

```
    namespace Morse_Device_Stuff
{
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private SerialPort port;


        private bool recordStarted = false;

        private void recordButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
            port.Open();
            recordStarted = !recordStarted;
            string lane;

            if(recordStarted)
            {

                (recordButton.Content as Image).Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("stop.png", UriKind.Relative));


                port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

            }

            else
            {
                (recordButton.Content as Image).Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("play.png", UriKind.Relative));
            }

            port.Close();
        }

        private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += port.ReadExisting();
        }
    }
}
```

After pressing the button nothing changes and my TextBox is still empty.

What's wrong than?

Comment: possible duplicate of [data receiving from serial port via WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070028/data-receiving-from-serial-port-via-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Port is closed inside recordButton_Click function. Since DataReceived is called asynchronously, nothing happens. Make SerialPort port variable class member, and remove port.Close line from recordButton_Click.

You can close the port in another place,for example, when the form is closed.

Also, you should not change textBox.Text directly inside port_DataReceived function, because it is called in arbitrary thread context. Use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to redirect this action to main application thread.